# Laravel Login multiple systems without logout when logged out from one system

Tags: authentication, session-cookies, laravel-5.8, laravel-authorization, laravel-admin

I am using laravel 5.8 and session based login (session store in db) with remember me token but I have a issue if I log out from one device, other device (in session timeout) also  gets logged out because when I logged out from one system its remember me token gets destroyed from db and the other system session expires and tries to re-authenticate based on remember me token that does not match.

can I store the remember me token in session table?